# Grails Melody plugin no longer logs SQL calls as of grails 2.0

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

Ever since I upgraded my two grails projects to grails 2.0 grails-melody stopped logging sql calls. I've tried different versions of the grails-melody plugin, but I get the same error across all versions (even the version that worked before migrating to grails 2.0).

I can't seem to find anything useful googling. If I add a trace debug on the grails melody plugin

```
log4j = {
    trace 'net.bull.javamelody'
}
```

I see this in the logs:

```
DEBUG bull.javamelody  - datasources found in JNDI: []
```

This problem is really driving me crazy.. Has anyone here experienced this problem? And if so did you find a solution?

UPDATE:
Grails melody doesn't even work in newly created projects. I just created a new grails project (grails 2.0.0) with one domain class and corresponding controller and views. Then installed the grails-melody plugin. Inserted some data. When I looked into the monitoring console, no sql data is being logged..

[image: Graph]
[image: Tables]

Answer (score 4):

A partial workaround is to set `jdbc.factory_class` in the hibernate section of `DataSource.groovy`.  For example:

```
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
    jdbc.factory_class = 'net.bull.javamelody.HibernateBatcherFactory'
}
```

This will log all the SQL queries that go through hibernate.  Queries that use the datasource directly still don't get logged.

Comment: Nice! Will try it out. Thanks!!

Comment: 1 down, one to go :) Need to find a solution for pure SQL calls (have a fair number of those for performance sake)

Comment: This worked for my needs, since I mostly wanted _some_ visibility into my SQL calls, and all, at this point, are going through Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

I upped ataylor's answer as it got me started fixing the issue.  But I cannot comment yet, so I'll post this here.

In the JDBC section on the JavaMelody docs: [JDBC](http://code.google.com/p/javamelody/wiki/UserGuide#7._JDBC), it outlines how to do this with straight hibernate using their own Driver facade.  I would assume this would work as well, except I cannot for the life of me figure out the parameters to put in DataSource.groovy to make it work.

Reference:

```
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">net.bull.javamelody.JdbcDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myschema</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">myuser</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">mypassword</property>
```