# Is there a preferred way of logging sql statements?

Tags: sql, grails, logging, grails-orm

i want to log sql generated by an application and have started to read about sql logging in a Grails application.

I tried to set the logSql = true setting but this gives me an unreadable set of sql and parameters. (a lot of parameters that are difficult to map to the sql statement)

Is there a prefered way of logging the sql so one can track the sql and look for performance bottlenecks? Should is use log4jdbc for example?

All hints and tips are welcome!

Comment: There are really a lot of questions on here about this that have very good answers. You should search first

Comment: I have seen that there are a lot of questions with a lot of different answers. I am just asking if there is a prefered way!

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to monitor the performance of SQL queries in a grails application is with the [JavaMelody plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/grails-melody).  Melody keeps track of the number of times each query is run along with the average and worst run times.  It also provides a simple interface to examine this and other runtime statistics about your app.

Unfortunately, it has some issues with grails 2.0: [Grails Melody plugin no longer logs SQL calls as of grails 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809805/grails-melody-plugin-no-longer-logs-sql-calls-as-of-grails-2-0)